# How to filter Data type with realm in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, filter, realm

I want to filter Data in realm but I don't know how, can you help me please:
I have an Array like

```
dt = [String:String] //[key:code]
```

And I use Realm like this:

```
_realm?.objects(Article.self).filter(" dt contains %@", _ean).first
```

And I want to know if an element exist in this Data
Thanks!

Comment: Your question is really unclear at the moment. There's no variable of type `Data`, so your title is clearly misleading. `dt` is not an `Array`, but a `Dictionary`. What is it you are actually trying to achieve with your realm query? Are your trying to filter the keys or the values of the `Dictionary`? Are you trying to query all `Article` objects from realm that are contained as keys/values in `dt`?

Comment: I just want to get an element in an dictionary. For example ["a":1,"b":2] I want to know if the value 2 exist.